# How do I visit a file on a different branch?

Tags: magit, git, vc

I'm aware of `C-x v ~` which allows you to see a different revision of the current file, but I would like to visit the file on another branch.

Is this possible with magit, VC or git-timemachine?

Comment: As you're using git, note that there is no practical difference between a branch name and any arbitrary git commit/revision of your repository.  They are all 'refs' representing the repository at a particular point in time.  Branches and Tags are simply human-friendly names which point to a ref.  So you can use these things interchangeably in most situations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I was confused because the options to choose from for `C-x v ~` only showed older revisions of the file on this particular branch, but you can in fact specify a branch and have that file shown.

Ie. if you want to visit the current file on master:

```
C-x v ~
```

Then just specify

```
master
```

As suggested by @KyleMeyer, the Magit command for this would be

```
magit-find-file-other-window
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer here to resolve the question.

Comment: For reference, the analogous command in Magit is `magit-find-file-other-window`.

Comment: I can't upvote comments yet, but thanks for the input guys!